# Abort running code on form when form is disposed?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I have a large, complex client application I am now maintaining.  For security purposes, it requires a constant connection to the server.  It has a thread that is handling all the socket communication between itself and the server.

The way it's currently written, if there is any communication issue with the server, the communications thread fires off an event that closes and disposes all open forms and returns the user back to the initial connection/logon screen.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes this communication issue can happen in the middle of the execution of a function (such as one that is blocked by a modal form).  When the modal form and parent form are disposed of, the function still finishes running, often leading to exceptions and errors.

For example, the report form has a function that opens a dialog, accepts input, and then runs a report based on that input:

```
'Inside the class for the ReportForm:

Private Sub RunReport()
    'Run code that requests list of reports from server
    _ReportSelectionForm = New frmReportSelection(reportList)
    _ReportSelectionForm.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.AddOwnedForm(_ReportSelectionForm)
    _ReportSelectionForm.ShowDialog(Me)

    'the following code will still execute when ReportForm (Me) is disposed:

    username = _ReportSelectionForm.txtUsername

    If (_ReportSelectionForm.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ok) Then
        'Run code
    ElseIf (_ReportSelectionForm.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) Then
        'Run different code
    End If  

    'etc
End Sub
```

So, if the Report Selection Form is open and the communications thread times out communications with the server, the communications error event fires which closes and disposes the ReportForm.  This, in turn, closes the _ReportSelectionForm Dialog.  When this happens, even though the parent form has been disposed, finishes running the code after "_ReportSelectionForm.ShowDialog(Me)".  This throws an exception on "_ReportSelectionForm.DialogResult" or "_ReportSelectionForm.txtUsername" because _ReportSelectionForm is Nothing.

If this was one isolated place, I could handle this with a few extra checks before continuing to run the function, but it's all over this large program.

What's the best way to handle this?  Can I abort code execution on a form that I'm closing?

Hopefully I explained it adequately.  My Google-Fu is failing me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search your solution for "CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls".  Delete that code and do it properly.

Comment: I searched the entire solution and came up with nothing for that term.  I remember seeing that in some of my searching and don't believe it's in use in this application.

The Communication event that closes and disposes all open forms invokes itself using a delegate before doing anything, which I think works around the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
Dim result as DialogResult = _ReportSelectionForm.ShowDialog(Me)

If (result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ok) Then
    'Run code
ElseIf (result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) Then
    'Run different code
End If
```

That way you're not referencing the `ReportSelectionForm`.

Comment: That's definitely better practice.  However there are other parts in the function that might error out, so this wouldn't necessarily solve all the problems.  For example, I edited the code example above because this particular function also accesses _ReportSelectionForm.txtUsername, which would encounter the same error.

Comment: The code shouldn't access `_ReportSelectionForm.txtUsername` unless the return value is `DialogResult.Ok`. And since it won't be (at least, it shouldn't because you cancel the dialog), this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Heh, you're absolutely right. My example was poor.  There are other places in the code where just grabbing the dialog result wont work because the code is also accessing something from the form, such as _ReportSelectionForm.txtUsername (edited example above).  There are many many places in the program where such errors occur and they won't all be solved by accessing the result like that.  But maybe there isn't a way to abort running these scripts and I'll just have to go through and identify all these places and put in an "if(frmExampleDialog Is Nothing)" check manually.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Select Case` would be better, perhaps?

Comment: The conditional statement is not the problem.  Errors are happening outside checks for the dialog's result.  See the code example in original post.